# Is there anyway to be able to reference xml/text columns in the "inserted" and "deleted" tables in a SQL Server 2008 (CLR) trigger?

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, sqlclr

I get an exception when I "Select * from deleted" in a clr trigger in SQL Server 2008. Is there anyway to be able to access xml/text columns from the deleted and inserted tables in a trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert your text and xml columns to varchar(max)

Comment: sorry should have been more descriptive. what you want can't be done. so best solution is to convert the xml column to varchar. this is a limitation of the system.